# How to Configure Heroku to host files using gzip compression

Tags: node.js, heroku, unity-game-engine, gzip

I am trying to deploy a **node.js app on heroku** ,
which is serving unity webGL exported game to clients.
After Unity3d 5+ release , **WebGL exports by Unity uses gzip compression** by default .

Well ,

> heroku server [Node.js] dont serves gzip compressed files , which is
>   causing my Game to throw error in console on load , main unity loading
>   window wont update (just blank) till files dont get completely
>   download & a slight delay while browser manually decompresses it.

[image]These are the file types Unity WebGL Export provides = || **.** datagz || **.** jsgz || **.** memgz  ||

So what i need is , a way to configure heroku node.js server for serving the gzip compression .

Comment: Your existing nodejs server code? You should post at least that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like you are having issues serving gzipped files. The messages in the console could be a separate issue altogether.

What is more likely is that your node app is not serving the right folder or files. If you can provide a list of files that is in your build folder (I assume that this is where Unity places its files), I can take a look.

Also, do review your Heroku configuration, namely the command used by the web process. If it is `npm start` or something, then look at the script it points to (see in your `package.json` file), and see if it is serving files out of the build folder.